# Can't get the right memory map using uefi's GetMemoryMap function

Tags: c, operating-system, bootloader, osdev, uefi

I'm writing a little boot loader in **UEFI** environment for my custom os using **POSIX-UEFI**.

When trying to get the memory map using **GetMemoryMap** boot service to calculate the amount of memory, it returns not only a different number of memory descriptors each time the program is executed, but the descriptor table itself seems to be corrupted or something...

Here's the code to get the memory map:

```
efi_memory_descriptor_t *map = NULL;
uintn_t mapsize, mapkey, descriptorsize;
uint32_t descriptorversion;
uint64_t memory_size = 0;

ST->BootServices->GetMemoryMap(&mapsize, map, &mapkey, &descriptorsize, &descriptorversion);
ST->BootServices->AllocatePool(EfiLoaderData, mapsize, (void **) &map);
ST->BootServices->GetMemoryMap(&mapsize, map, &mapkey, &descriptorsize, &descriptorversion);
printf("Memory map size: %d descriptors\n", mapsize / descriptorsize);

for (int i = 0; i < mapsize / descriptorsize; i++) {
    efi_memory_descriptor_t *desc = (efi_memory_descriptor_t *)(map + i * descriptorsize);
    memory_size += desc->NumberOfPages * EFI_PAGE_SIZE;
}

printf("Memory size: %d bytes\n", memory_size);
```

I tried using `sizeof(efi_memory_descriptor_t)` too instead of descriptorsize to calculate the number of entries but nothing changes.

Here's a screenshot of the program's output:
[VirtualBox with an efi shell running 3 times the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3jex.png)

I use a VirtualBox (v7.0.4) virtual machine with 64MB ram size, no storage device, and a usb drive attached to load the program from.

Comment: Calling AllocatePool may change  the number of descriptors, so you should add some slop (2 x descriptorsize) to map size before calling GetMemoryMap the second time. You should also check the return values.

Comment: This isn't a very good way to get the amount of memory. If you want available memory,  only add up the descriptors of type 7 (EfiConventionalMemory), which represents free memory. Depending on your usage, you may also want to add some of the other types, but definitely not reserved, MMIO, or runtime services, for example. If you want the total amount of memory in the system, just look for the descriptor with the highest ending address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` is a pointer to efi_memory_descriptor_t, so `map + i * descriptorsize` is scaling by both descriptorsize and sizeof (efi_memory_descriptor_t).

I suggest using `(uint8_t *)map + i * descriptorsize`.

Note, descriptorsize may not be equal to sizeof (efi_memory_descriptor_t), so it is correct to use descriptorsize.

Comment: Almost - should be "(uint8_t *) map + i * descriptorsize". I upvoted anyway.